# Composite unique constraint with boolean value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table structured as below,

```
tests
---------------------------
schoolId  | name  | isDeleted
```

I don't want to allow duplicate test name for an school if it is active i.e `isDeleted = false`

I am not sure how can I put unique constraint for fields taking only one value for boolean fields `isDeleted=false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could do something like below,

```
create unique index tests_unique_name_schoolId_notDeleted
    on tests (name, schoolId) where isDeleted = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the query of the index like the below query:

```
create unique index tests_unique_name_schoolId_notDeleted
    on tests (name) where isDeleted = false;
```

The `name` and `isDeleted` columns should be mixed up together and put `where isDeleted = false` means only a row is unique when `isDeleted` is false when the `name` column is the same. On the other hand, you can store too many records with `isDeleted = true` and these rows not be unique and not stored in the index.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d508ad6b363151af6e7f23108ed76b1e)

Comment: Yes, no need for this column. I fixed that